# Windows 10 Bluetooth Audio Playback Device

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth speaker connected to my Windows 10 PC. However, I have noticed that there are two different playback devices, namely the Headphones and Headset device. It seems that the Headphones device automatically stops working when I enter a video call. Windows also does not automatically switch the audio devices, so I have to manually switch to the Headset device in order for it to work. So my question is:

1. What is the difference between these two devices?
2. Can I make Windows automatically switch between these two devices?

[image: Screenshot of select playback device]

Comment: How to add an inline image.  Copy and paste in the body.

Comment: @somebadhat any idea on how to solve this?